# Java debugger can't see variables some times (often inside anonymous inner classes)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Java debugger can't see variables some times.

Proof:

[image]

Often this occurs inside anonymous inner classes while variable is "closure" (I know this is not exact term here). If "closure" is class member variable, I can see it if prepend with `MyClass.this.myvariable`, but if it is method local variable, then I can't see it at all.

Is there any way to see such variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot see final variable content inside anonymous class when debugging in Eclipse an Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496842/cannot-see-final-variable-content-inside-anonymous-class-when-debugging-in-eclip)

Comment: Usually it helps to browse _Outline_ tab for such variables... Not so convenient but at least you can always find them there.

Answer (score 1):

please check that the code you are running is in sync with code in your IDE.
- you may have change code while application is running and it will change line
- sometime eclipse does not run updated code, try to do clean build and restart app.