# Debugging JMock expectations

Tags: java, eclipse, jmock

When I'm in an expectations block, I can't inspect variables in Eclipse debug.  I get "errors during evaluation" in the expressions window and "id cannot be resolved to a variable" when right clicking on the "id" variable.

For example< I can't inspect dataQuery:

```
DataQuery dataQuery = context.mock(DataQuery.class);
String id = "Test";

content.checking(new Expectations() {{
    oneOf(dataQuery).getProperty(id);
}}
```

Inside the block, I can hit F3 on id and it takes me to the declaration.  The code is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=95842#c4) with anonymous classes. Also discussed on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496842/cannot-see-final-variable-content-inside-anonymous-class-when-debugging-in-eclip) thread.

From the comments on the eclipse issue it seems like the local final variables are visible in the debugger as members of anonymous class object this. (I don't see it in my local workspace though):

> Those fields are usually named `val$<original_var_name>`, if the class
>   was compiled with the jdt compiler.

The comments also hint that it is JVMDI API (jvm debugger interface) limitation and not a problem in eclipse:

> I assume that someone somewhere has asked for that feature,  and I
>   assume that they were told that it was not possible using JVMDI API...
>   ?